# Syntax error 'Unexpected token, expected }' is thrown after trying to render JSX inside a callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, jsx

In the following snippet of code, I am iterating over the object's properties (PADS in this case), using the `lodash` library `map` method. It accepts the object, and a callback function as arguments.

Another mention would be that I am trying to incorporate bootstrap features with a react child component.

```
let count = 0;
let countCount = 0;
const drumPadItems = _.map(PADS, padElem => {
    count++;
    countCount++;

    if(countCount === 1){
      return (
        <div className="row">
        <DrumPad letter={padElem.letter} url={padElem.url}/>
      );
    }

    if(count > 3){
      count = 1;
      return (</div><div className="row"><DrumPad letter={padElem.letter} url={padElem.url}/>
      );
    }

    if(countCount === 9){
        return (
          <DrumPad letter={padElem.letter} url={padElem.url}/>
          </div>
        );
    }

    return <DrumPad letter={padElem.letter} url={padElem.url}/>;
});
```

When I run the application, I get the following compilation error:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/drum_pad_list.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected } (76:19)
 if(count > 3){
  count = 1;
           ^
  return (</div><div className="row"><DrumPad letter={padElem.letter} url={padElem.url}/>
 );
}
```

**EDIT:**

The `PADS` object has the following structure:

```
{
    q: {
        label: "Label1",
        letter: "Q",
        url: "https://..."
    },
    w: {
        label: "Label2",
        letter: "W",
        url: "https://..."
    }
    ...
}
```

The desired output would be something like the following:

```
<div className="row">
  <DrumPad letter='Q' url='https://...'/>
  <DrumPad letter='W' url='https://...'/>
  <DrumPad letter='E' url='https://...'/>
</div>
```

What would be a solution for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSX is incomplete as there is no closing `</div>`. You have several incomplete JSX and you cannot "concat" partial JSX. This will fix the first:

```
<div className="row">
  <DrumPad letter={padElem.letter} url={padElem.url} />
</div>
```

To map 9 of your elements you can do this (the `key` prop must be unique and is required for React's bookkeeping):

```
// use capitalize for function name
const DrumPadItems = () => (
  <div className="row">
    {
      Object.values(PADS)
        .slice(0, 9)
        .map(padElem => <DrumPad 
          letter={padElem.letter} 
          url={padElem.url} 
          key={padElem.letter} />)
    }
  </div>
)
```

This will "render" a list of:

```
<div className="row">
  <DrumPad />
  <DrumPad />
  ...
</div>
...
```

I'd recommend to use object destructuring and to make PADS a prop and then you can use it like that:

```
const DrumPadItems = ({PADS}) => (
  <div className="row">
    {
      Object.values(PADS)
        .slice(0, 9)
        .map(({letter, url}) => <DrumPad 
          letter={letter} 
          url={url} 
          key={letter} />)
    }
  </div>
)


// somewhere else
<div>
  <DrumPadItems PADS={this.state.PADS} />
  <OtherStuff />
</div>
```

BTW: you don't need lodash assuming that `PADS` is an Array.

Comment: That is not possible the way you try to do it. You cannot concat JSX as a string.

Comment: Is there a way to somehow insert a child `DrumPad` element inside that `row` div ?

Comment: Can you edit your question, so we can see what your desired output is?

Comment: I edited the question with the desired output. In this case I am using an object, not an array.

Comment: `{ q: {
    label: "Label1",
    letter: "Q",
    url: "https://..."
  },
  w: {
    label: "Label2",
    letter: "W",
    url: "https://..."
  } ... }`

Comment: you should capitalize `drumPadItems` to make clear this is a functional component.

Comment: Looking at the desired output, why don't you remove the `<div>` from the mapping and replace `<React.Fragment>` with it?

Comment: @R.Duteil because this is the desired output from the question.

Answer (score 0):

1) You are missing `</div>`

```
 if(countCount === 1){
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <DrumPad letter={padElem.letter} url={padElem.url}/>
    </div> {/* DIV MISSING */}
  );
}
```

2) Too much `<div>`

```
if(count > 3){
  count = 1;
  return (
    </div> {/* TOO MUCH DIV */}
    <div className="row">
      <DrumPad letter={padElem.letter} url={padElem.url}/>
    </div> {/* DIV MISSING */}
  );
}
```

3) You are missing `</div>`

```
if(countCount === 9){
    return (
      <div> {/* DIV MISSING */}
         <DrumPad letter={padElem.letter} url={padElem.url}/>
      </div>
    );
}
```

JSX wants the entire return markup into a one container like `return(<div>...</div>);`

I believe there is another way to do what you want, if you explain it to us